# W/PersistentConnection(23823): pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.(for firebase name)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

W/PersistentConnection(23823): pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly.

I get this error for this code:

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("trips");
```

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query:databaseRef,
            itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double>animation, int index){
              var x=snapshot.value;
              print(x);
        return ListTile(
          subtitle: Text('Hey'),
      title: Text('hello'),
      //       subtitle:Text(snapshot.value['subtitle']),
      //       // subtitle: Text(snapshot.value?['title']??"default"),
      // title:Text(snapshot.value['subtitle'])

              );
      },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that your `google-services.json` or `firebase_options.dart` file either has the wrong database URL, or doesn't have a database URL at all.

You can either download an updated `google-services.json` file from the Firebase console, regenerate `firebase_options.dart` from the Firebase console, or specify the correct database URL (which you can find in the Firebase console) in the call to [`instanceFor`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/instanceFor.html) (instead of `instance`).